# Como reverter o git push --force?

Tags: git, github

Fiz um `git push --force`, mas gostaria de ter feito `git push --force-with-lease` é possível reverter isso?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se você não estragou o trabalho de ninguém ao fazer o git push --force - não tem por que voltar atrás e fazer o outro. Se estragou, fazer o "force-with-lease" também não ajuda nada: ele só iria se recusar ao fazer o push.

Tudo o que o `git push --force-with-lease` faz é verificar se vai sobreescrever algum trabalho do qual o seu repositório local ainda não sabia.

Por exemplo: se você fizer um `git fetch` o `push --force` e `push --force-with-lease` são indistinguíveis: o segundo é tão destruidor como o primeiro.

- **caso você tenha sobre-escrito o trabalho de terceiros**:  isso é ruim!  E é parte do motivo por que não se deve usar git push --force (com ou sem "with-lease") no workflow do time.

  1. **Pare o trabalho do time** *agora* e chame para uma reunião online. Há o risco do trabalho perdido não poder ser recuperado se todo mundo não fizer isso
  2. As informações sobre-escritas pelo `git push --force` no servidor remoto (seja github/gitlab/bitbucket), não são mais recuperáveis a partir de lá. Kaput! Fim! Mortas! (exceção se o servidor remoto for um serviço sob seu controle e não uma hospedagem de git na nuvem). (eu já disse que não é bom usar `git push --force`?)
  3. A boa notícia é que elas podem ser recuperadas na máquina de quem tinha o trabalho que foi sobrescrito. Então, usando a sua reunião online, identifique quem teve o trabalho sobrescrito, e com calma pra não piorar as coisas:

     1. Se a pessoa ainda não fez um `git pull` ou `git fetch`, ela simplesmente faz um `git push --force` de volta, e o trabalho dela que foi perdido no servidor é restaurado no servidor. Combinem que a partir de amanhã vocês vão usar branches separados pra trabalhar, e podem ir para um happy hour agora;
     2. se a pessoa fez um "pull" e ignorou os avisos de segurança do git de que o branch remoto e o seu local divergiram, e sobrescreveu o branch local dela com o branch remoto,  que foi danificado  pelo `push --force` dado incorretamente - o time está na roça, mas tem saída:
     3. A pessoa que teve o trabalho sobre-escrito tem que usar o comando `git reflog`. Com esse comando deve dar pra achar o commit que estava anteriormente no servidor da nuvem. Ela pode agora criar um novo branch com esse commit, recupeando o trabalho sobre-escrito - basta copiar o hash do commit perdido e fazer: `git branch branch_restauracao <id-do-commit-perdido>` - pronto, ela vai ter um branch local, na máquina dela, com o trabalho que tinha sido sobre-escrito no servidor
     4. Agora a pessoa pode simplesmente subir esse branch "branc_restauracao" para o servidor, e abrir um pull request normal por lá para recuperar o trabalho que foi sobre-escrito. Vocês vão pra um happy hour; amanhã volta todo mundo e combina de trabalhar com branches e pull requests para o branch principal; todos ficam felizes!

Em resumo: provavelmente não precisa fazer nada. Mas o melhor mesmo é rever as práticas do seu time para evitar `git push --force` - seja `"--with-lease"` ou não.

O git provê bastante flexibilidade e formas de trabalho diferentes para realmente, o único ponto onde pode ser interessante realizar um "push --force" é quando estiver fazendo o "rebase" de um branch - isso é, atualizando um branch de desenvolvimento separado a partir do branch master, mas de forma que os commits no master que ocorreram depois da separação do branch de desenvolvimento atual fiquem todos na "base", e não como um commit separado dentro do branch atual.

Na prática, ainda não trabalhei com nenhum projeto real que tenha um nível de maturidade e/ou complexidade dos branchs tal que os "rebase" realmente se fizessem necssários - o uso de "merge", evitando o rebase pode muito bem ser o suficiente, e evitar os "push force".

Fora isso, com o uso apropriado de branchs e políticas de merge de volta no branch principal, não vejo por que usar "push --force"

Comment: Na verdade ninguém mexeu nesse branch, só eu mesmo... mas tá tudo bem, não estraguei nada... :), eu acho que só perdi o commit que eu tinha deletado 2 arquivos, pois é... eu tive que deletar novamente, mas obrigado!

Comment: o roteiro já fica aí para o caso do dia que alguém se encrencar -