# Existe um meio de apagar comentários de um commit do github?

Tags: git, github, commit

Existe algum meio de apagar o comentário de um commit? Ou existe um arquivo invisível que salva esses comentários e registros?(seja nos arquivos do pc ou no do repositório no site).

Pode ser apagar todos ou um a um.

Tenho um repositorio importante no github que tem alguns comentários errados e preciso tira-los, pesquisei e vi que tem como retornar commits, mas ai iria apagar as alterações.

Ja tentei clonar meu próprio repositorio e upar de novo e ele vem com os comentários.

Comment: Os comentários **fazem parte** do commit, não tem como remover somente eles e manter o mesmo commit. O único jeito de se livrar delas é reescrevendo o histórico: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History - lembrando que reescrever o histórico pode afetar pessoas que já clonaram seu repositório antes

Comment: Obrigado amigo, funcionou, ao dar git log aparece as modificações que eu queria, porem tem um problema, no site continua igual, vc saberia oque fazer? n sei se n achei na doc, mas estou procurando.

Comment: Se "no site" vc quer dizer "no GitHub", é porque vc tem que sincronizar suas alterações, provavelmente com `git push -f` - mas cuidado, como eu já disse, esse comando pode afetar pessoas que já clonaram seu repositório antes: entenda o motivo lendo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/458820/112052) e [aqui](https://salferrarello.com/never-git-push-force/)

Comment: sem problemas, meu rep esta privado

Comment: O unico problema é que não pode alterar o primeiro commit, o meu git tem 8, vc so poderia abrir 7, e se coloca HEAD~0 abre uma tela com "noop"

Comment: Achei, so colocar como --root.
Porem toda vez que tem a mudança acaba excluindo alguns arquivos, no fim n esta sendo efetivo