# Tem como apagar commits anteriores e permanecer apenas o atual?

Tags: git, github

Enquanto eu estava modificando o README do perfil, acabei fazendo muitas tentativas e resolvendo alguns erros, isso me gerou 90 commits em um único arquivo.

Eu gostaria de saber se dá pra apagar todos os commits anteriores e deixar apenas o atual.

Meu perfil: https://github.com/tayhsn

Comment: Sim é possível.

Comment: otimoo. você pode me dizer como? por favorrr

Comment: deu pra ver que eu sou bem iniciante né kkkkk fiz cento e tanta alterações pra chegar num resultado, imagina eu me aventurando nisso ai, não quero bugar tudo

Comment: Achei muito legal o perfil do github, de onde eu pego o template? Parabéns.

Comment: https://github.com/anuraghazra/github-readme-stats o stats e o most used languages foi desse repositorio

Comment: obrigado!! tive muito trabalho pra fazer dá certo kkkkk mas deu. agora só quero deixar mais arrumado, eu tenho 10x commits que repositorios. Ah, se quiser saber sobre as habilidades, é so abrir o raw do readme e copiar, eh o jeito mais facil

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5189560

Comment: obrigado, mas não tenho certezase entendi muito bem. voce poderia me passar o comando?

Answer (score 6):

Não sei se pela interface do GitHub dá para fazer, mas de qualquer forma eu prefiro a linha de comando.

Primeiro você clona o repositório na sua máquina:

```
git clone http://url.do.repositorio
```

Obviamente, trocando `url.do.repositorio` pela URL do repositório que você quer mexer.

Depois, para voltar 90 commits e "juntar" tudo em um só:

```
git reset --soft HEAD~90
git commit -m "juntando 90 commits"
```

A mensagem "juntando 90 commits" pode ser trocada pelo que você quiser, claro.

Basicamente, `HEAD~90` significa "[90 commits pra trás](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2221658)" e `reset --soft` volta para esse commit, mas sem modificar os arquivos ([leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/325951/112052) para entender melhor o que `git reset` faz).

Ou seja, eu volto 90 commits para trás, mas sem modificar o conteúdo atual dos arquivos. E depois faço um `commit`, que terá todas as alterações dos 90 commits (pois o conteúdo dos arquivos não estará alterado).

Em outras palavras, o repositório estava assim:

```
commit 1
commit 2
....
commit 90
commit 91 <-- estou aqui
```

Voltando 90 commits, eu passo a ficar no primeiro, mas o conteúdo dos arquivos continua sendo igual ao commit 91:

```
commit 1 <-- após git reset --soft HEAD~90, estou aqui
...
commit 91 <-- mas o conteúdo dos arquivos continua igual a este
```

Após o `git commit`:

```
commit 1
commit novo <-- novo commit, contendo o conteúdo dos 90 commits (do 2 ao 91)
```

**Aliás, esse é um detalhe importante**: se você tem exatamente 90 commits, para voltar ao primeiro você deve usar `HEAD~89`.

Outro detalhe é que todo esse processo criará um **novo** commit, e os anteriores ficarão de fora da "árvore" (não será possível chegar a eles, já que eles foram "perdidos" e substituídos pelo novo commit).  Lembrando que assim você ficará com 2 commits (o primeiro e o novo).

Por isso ao mandar para o GitHub, você deverá fazer `git push -f` para sobrescrever os commits antigos. Só [leia aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/458820/112052) para entender as implicações de um "push force".

E em vez de usar a quantidade, você também pode fazer o `reset` para um commit específico, usando o hash do mesmo:

```
git reset --soft hash-do-commit
```

Sendo que o hash é aquele texto enorme que aparece no `git log`. Exemplo:

```
$ git log
commit a493c0d479c37cbec9c9899d4fb97c323b7c3364 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Fulano
Date:   2018-09-01 13:12:01

    juntando tudo

commit 36da3462ecbce934cd88c96d8a3205ca25b5a489
Author: Fulano
Date:   2018-09-01 13:11:45

    primeiro commit
```

No caso, a493c0d479c37cbec9c9899d4fb97c323b7c3364 e 36da3462ecbce934cd88c96d8a3205ca25b5a489 são os hashes dos 2 commits existentes.

---

Outra forma é usar `rebase`.

Fiz um exemplo, com apenas 4 commits:

```
$ git log --oneline 
7566a92 (HEAD -> master) quarto commit
668185f terceiro commit
8bc39c6 segundo commit
36da346 primeiro commit
```

E quero juntar tudo em um só, então basta fazer:

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

Repare que o maior valor possível em `HEAD~N` é a quantidade de commits menos 1.

Isso vai abrir uma tela assim:

```
pick 8bc39c6 segundo commit
pick 668185f terceiro commit
pick 7566a92 quarto commit

... mais um monte de informações
```

No "monte de informações" tem uma breve explicação das opções disponíveis. Para juntar os commits, eu escolho a opção "squash", ou simplesmente "s". Então basta editar as informações para ficar assim:

```
pick 8bc39c6 segundo commit
s 668185f terceiro commit
s 7566a92 quarto commit

... o resto você não mexe
```

Ou seja, o primeiro da lista eu mantenho, o restante eu junto (faço o "squash").

Depois abrirá outra tela/editor com as mensagens de commit de todos os commits envolvidos na operação (ou seja, no seu caso vai aparecer todas as 90 mensagens).

Edite a mensagem e salve. Todos os commits serão unidos em um só (lembrando que você terminará também com 2 commits: o primeiro e o novo que foi gerado agora).

Depois também será necessário fazer o `git push -f` para atualizar o repositório remoto.

No caso de 90 commits, esse processo é um pouco mais chato porque você teria que editar muitas linhas, e por isso a primeira opção acima (com `reset`) me parece mais rápida.

Answer (score 5):

Quero propor mais uma opção além das descritas pelo [hkotsubo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/491560/13561):

- refazer o *commit*
- *rebase* interativo com *squash*
- ***merge* com *squash***

Para fazer o *merge* com *squash* vou demonstrar juntando os últimos 8 *commits* de histórico abaixo:

```
* b992307 (HEAD -> main, origin/main) Preload above the fold assets
* 0c056bf Tune responsive and supported styles
* 689ae42 Add logo in english page
* 558897c Fix typo
* 7a75bed Add social preview meta tags
* a77ab4e Update background fallback color
* f0ed2ee Reduce code indent size
* aec4690 Add fallback background color, reduce CSS
* 8980c33 Merge 'look-and-feel' into main
```

1. identificar o primeiro *commit* para unificar: `aec4690 Add fallback...`
2. copiar a identificação do commit anterior: `8980c33`
3. criar uma ramificação temporária nesse *commit*: `git checkout -b tmp 8980c33`
4. mesclar a ramificação com *squash*: `git merge --squash main`
5. fazer commit (*squash merge* não faz o *commit*): `git commit -m "Descrição ..."`
6. remover a ramificação anterior: `git branch -D main`
7. renomear ramificação temporária para principal: `git branch -m tmp main`
8. enviar para o remoto forçando sobrescrita: `git push -f origin main`

---

Nota: **é preciso tomar bastante cuidado ao reescrever o histórico do GIT, se outras pessoas usam o repositório ou é de um projeto público esse ação vai "quebrar" o histórico para as outras pessoas. Sempre leve isso em consideração quando precisar fazer alguma ação de reescrita de histórico, se possível use um processo alternativo.**