# Como reutilizar os conteúdos de uma branch para outra?

Tags: git, github

Atualmente tenho um projeto com duas branch, <**main**> e <**development**>. A <**development**> eu uso para desenvolver aquilo que pretendo fazer, e cada versão "final" daquilo que termino. Ai vem a <**main**>, que pretendo passar essa versão "finalizada" do <**development**> para a <**main**>. Como faço isso? Ja tentei usar o comando marge e outros semelhantes mas não atendeu aquilo que eu queria. Eu tento fazer o git push usando a branch <**development**> pra <**main**> mas ele da esse erro:

> ! [rejected]        main -> main (non-fast-forward)
> error: failed to push some refs to ''
> hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
> hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
> PS C:<diretorio-local-pc>> git checkout development
> resources/views/dashboard.blade.php
> Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
> Aborting.

Comment: O comando seria o `merge`, de fato. Ou, como está utilizando o Github, pode abrir o PULL REQUEST da `development` para a `main`.

Comment: @Woss como faço essa alteração no repositorio remoto? Eu fiz o marge e ele pega as alterações que fiz de uma branch pra outra, mas como pego essas alterações e subo? Eu não estou conseguindo subir. OBS: Esse projeto é novo e minha MAIN, que é o nome da minha branch principal, está vazia. Não sei se isso tem diferença. Minha intenção é passar o que ja está na DEVELOPMENT para a MAIN

Comment: @LucasMiranda cara, achei que não ia funcionar pois já havia tentado. Porém, eu usei o <git push origin main --force>. Eu não cheguei a usar o --force. Obrigado!!!

Comment: Se você é o único mexendo nesse repositório não tem muito problema usar `--force`, mas em todo caso é bom saber dos "perigos" de usá-lo: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/458820/112052